# Mixture of Poisson Additive Regression Model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

This is for a personal project (Just learnt EM algorithm and GAM model; and thinking about combine them together)

Believing that these data belongs to different clusters (where the labels are missing), and I want to do regression on them. Similar to mixture of expert that each regression take up its own data space

Now, consider we have a much more complicated nonlinear data, instead of doing mix of simple linear regression, I'm thinking doing mix of Poisson regression with additive model

So I'm thinking about mixture of regression using EM.The latent variable is the missing labels. So if I choose Poisson Regression with monomial basis functions
Latent variable is Z, poisson counts is Y, input data is X, d is dimension of each data.

So the likelihood would be $P(x) = \sum_k \alpha_k Poi(\lambda_k)$ where $\alpha_k$ is the weight for k-th cluster density

==============Updated================

Initialization: uniform outer weight $\alpha_k$ for each of GAM;  naive guess for each GAM coefficient $\beta$; where $GAM_k = \alpha_k(\beta_0 + \sum_{d=1}^D \beta_d \times f_{d,k}(x)$)

Repeat:

(1) for each data point, I compute the posterior of responsibility $p(Z=z|X) = \frac{\alpha_z Poi(\lambda_z)}{\sum_k \alpha_k Poi(\lambda_k)}$

(2) update outer weight 
$\alpha_z = \frac{\sum_x P(Z=z|x)}{N}$

(3) for each GAM: backfitting algorithm update coefficient to get a new $GAM_k'$. Then $GAM_k \leftarrow P(Z=z|x) \times GAM_k'$

========================================

Is this the approach you suggested?

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there should be a separate GAM for each Poisson mean. You can then fit each GAM using the latent probabilities as weights, or simply fit the GAM on the subset of the data $$S=\{x\in X: \mathop{\mathrm{argmax}}_i P(Z=i|X=x)=z\}$$ Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for reply; when you say  fit each GAM using the latent probabilities as weights. Since for a single GAM; we have mean $\beta_0 + \sum_d f_d(x)$; my intuition (From GMM) kind leads to think $\beta_0 +  \sum_d f_d( \alpha_k  x)$ where $\alpha_k$ is the weights to $k-$th GAM ? What confuses is that GMM is maximize the likelihood; but backfitting algorithm doesn't seem to use likelihood to udpate

Comment: By weights, I meant the weighted regression, such as changing the log-likelihood loss $\sum_{i=0}^N w_i \log Pois(y_i | \lambda_k(x_i))$. A generalized GAM is actually fit using a different algorithm that uses standard backfitting internally: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch13.pdf. These outer weights would simply be multiplied by the inner weights into the inner loops.

Comment: In the link, note the algorithm for GLM fitting. GAM is the same, using backfitting to fit the inner weighted AM (instead of a weighted LM).

Comment: Also, by latent probabilities, I mean the responsibilities $Z$.

Comment: Sorry for late reply; I have updated my post to reflect your suggestions; not sure if I misunderstood. I just have a little doubt that how am I sure that this approach actually gonna make it work? I kind feel uniform assigned initial outer weight gonna make the whole thing equilibrium; and algorithm actually doesn't update at all

Comment: Not quite. First, the updating of the outer weights should happen after the new coefficients are estimated as in a standard EM algorithm. Second, each GAM should be updated using the data pointwise responsibilities $z_ik$ as weights in the GAM regression. If you are using R, for example, this is done by supplying a vector as the `weights` parameter.

Comment: thanks for the reply; I'm using python, so responsibility matrix $R$ is $NxK$; ($K$ is num of GAMs),  for $k$-th GAM, consider the $k$ 's column of responsibility matrix pointwise apply multiplication to the $k$-th GAM (point wise to beta coefficient in k-th GAM)?

Comment: The weights are incorporated in the model fitting process, so the k-th column of R is used as weights when fitting the k-th GAM. Are you coding the BF algorithm yourself, or using a package? If you doing it yourself, you can incorporate the weights into the calculation of $\beta_0$ (weighted mean) and of the smoothing functions (e.g. weighted local regression). Also, the outer weights $\alpha_k$ should not be involved in the GAM fitting at all.

Comment: If you are using the pyGAM package, there is a weights parameter for GAM.fit.

Comment: I'm gonna code BF myself as a practice. I think u mean: our objective $min \sum_i w_i*(y^{(i)} - \beta_0 - \sum_d f_{d,k}^{(i)}(x_d^{(i)}))$; we make it like $min \sum_i P(Z=k|x^{(i)})*w_i*(y^{(i)} - \beta_0 - \sum_d f_{d,k}^{(i)}(x_d^{(i)}))$; this case, higher responsibility, more weighted assigned $GAM_k$. This $P(Z=k|x^{(i)})*w_i$ is the way we incorporate. I use superscript as data point.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct for the overall loss. What are the $w_i$, problem level weights (e.g. repeated examples, etc.)?

Comment: $w_i$ will be the local weights (such as variance )

Comment: Ok, I see. Also I misspoke: that form of the loss is correct for a plain AM, but a Poisson GAM will use the weighted log-likelihood instead of squared error.